# Why do i get a ObjectId failed for value error when i don't have a findByID or anything in nodeJs using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So the issue is that when I try to hit my “users” endpoint (everything that has something to do with users)  I get an error or not really an error it just cancels the call with no explanation, I then tried to open the request in a new tap here it give me the explanation you see in the screenshot. The weird thing is that my other endpoints works in the browser and the “users” endpoint works perfectly well in postman but in the browser, it gives me that error.

My User model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Pleas tell us your name'],
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please provide us your email'],
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true,
        validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please provide a valid email']
    },
    photo: {
        type: String,
        default: 'default.jpg'
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please provide a password'],
        minlength: 8,
        select: false
    },
    passwordConfirm: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please confirm your password'],
        validate: {
            //This only works on CREATE and SAVE!!!
            validator: function (el) {
                return el === this.password;
            },
            message: 'Passwords are not the same'
        }
    },
    passwordChangedAt: Date,
    passwordResetToken: String,
    passwordResetExpires: Date,
    active: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
        select: false
    }
});

userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();

    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 12);

    this.passwordConfirm = undefined;
    next();
});

userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    if (!this.isModified('password') || this.isNew) return next();

    this.passwordChangedAt = Date.now() - 1000;
    next();
});

userSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
    //This points to the current query
    this.find({
        active: {
            $ne: false
        }
    });
    next();
});

userSchema.methods.correctPassword = async function (candidatePassword, userPassword) {
    return await bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, userPassword);
}

userSchema.methods.changedPasswordAfter = function (JWTTimestamp) {
    if (this.passwordChangedAt) {

        const changedTimestamp = parseInt(this.passwordChangedAt.getTime() / 1000, 10)

        return JWTTimestamp < changedTimestamp
    }

    return false;
};

userSchema.methods.createPasswordResetToken = function () {
    const resetToken = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex')

    this.passwordResetToken = crypto
        .createHash('sha256')
        .update(resetToken)
        .digest('hex');

    this.passwordResetExpires = Date.now() + 10 * 60 * 1000;

    return resetToken;
}

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

The functions in the controller that is used

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const {
    promisify
} = require('util');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('./../models/userModel');
const catchAsync = require('./../utils/catchAsync');
const sendEmail = require('./../utils/email');

const AppError = require('../utils/appError');

const signToken = id => {
    return jwt.sign({
            id: id
        },
        process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
            expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN
        });
}

const createSendToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
    const token = signToken(user._id);
    const cookieOptions = {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
        httpOnly: true,
    }

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') cookieOptions.secure = true;
    res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);
    
    // Remove password from output
    user.password = undefined;

    res.status(statusCode).json({
        status: 'success',
        token,
        data: {
            user
        }
    })
}

exports.signup = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    const newUser = await User.create({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        passwordConfirm: req.body.passwordConfirm,
        passwordChangedAt: req.body.passwordChangedAt,
        role: req.body.role,
    });

    createSendToken(newUser, 201, res);
});

exports.login = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    const {
        email,
        password
    } = req.body;
    
    // 1) Check if email and password exist
    if (!email || !password) {
        return new AppError('Please provide email and password', 400);
    }
    
    //2) Check if user exist and the password is correct
    const user = await User.findOne({
        email
    }).select('+password');
    
    if (!user || !(await user.correctPassword(password, user.password))) {
        return next(new AppError('Incorrect email or password', 401))
    }
    
    //3) if everything is ok send token to client
    createSendToken(user, 200, res);
});
```

My dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^7.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-mongo-sanitize": "^1.3.2",
    "express-rate-limit": "^3.5.0",
    "helmet": "^3.16.0",
    "hpp": "^0.2.2",
    "html-to-text": "^5.1.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.3",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.1.1",
    "pug": "^2.0.3",
    "slugify": "^1.3.4",
    "stripe": "^7.0.0",
    "validator": "^10.11.0",
    "xss-clean": "^0.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.3",
    "prettier": "^1.17.0"
  },
```

As you can see I don't use findById or anything that would require mongoose to check for ObjectId, but it still says that is the error.

[The error I saw after opening the request in another browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axMb5.png)

Comment: The error message shows that it is trying to convert the string `"login"` into an ObjectId. This could be some misrouting (maybe `/users/:id` is defined before `/users/login`) or something is gone wrong with how the url is formulated on the frontend. Could you show your routes, and the frontend code which makes the request to the `login`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but I found out the issue, it was that my form element was reloading the page while the request was being made, which canceled it.